# Int to char array as a function returning an array of char the simple way

Tags: c, arrays

I have been looking on internet for this and so far i just found a lot of questions for specific answer and not a general one.

i am kind of rusty on C. And i want to make a function that will return an array of char.

this is what i got and is not working. basically a way to convert a byte array to an array of chars to do atoi later..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *get_char(int my_byte[], int packetsize)
{
    char *array_char=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);  //trying this but didnt work
     // char array_char[10]; //i had it like this before(was told to do it)

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            array_char[i]=my_byte[i]+0;
        }           

        return array_char;
    }

int main()
{

    int byte_array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    char *temp;
    char data;

    temp=get_char(byte_array,10);   
    data=*temp;
    printf("String  point %s ",data);

}
```

Comment: You want to add the `'0'` *character*, not the number zero.  After all, adding zero changes nothing.  That is: `array_char[i]=my_byte[i] + '0';`.

Comment: You *are* returning a (dynamically allocated) array of `char`.  If you want it to contain the string, "1234567890", you should add `'0'` instead of just `0` when you set each character... and make it 11 elements long (rather than 10), with the last element set to `0` (or `'\0'`) to mark the end of the string.

Comment: Change like as [this](http://ideone.com/MmSvkf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Not Wise Idea to Return a Array From A Function. So how to return a string then? As most of libc functions use we can use some thing like that (i.e) passing a buffer along with our input and expect function to use output buffer to give us result.

Some issue to take care while coding

1. write your logic first.
2. try to use available functions from libc.
3. while dealing with byte data/binary data be take precaution of buffer overflow.
4. don't allocate in a function and de-allocate in another function.

Below is Example of your code with modification.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int get_char(uint8_t my_byte[], int packetsize, char *buffer, int max_buffer)
{
        int byte_itr, buf_itr;
        char temp_buf[16]={0x00};
        for(byte_itr=0, buf_itr=0; byte_itr<packetsize && max_buffer > buf_itr; byte_itr++)
        {
                memset(temp_buf, 0x00, sizeof(temp_buf));
                char temp_ch = my_byte[byte_itr];
                snprintf(temp_buf, sizeof(temp_buf), "%d", temp_ch);
                if( buf_itr+strlen(temp_buf) >=max_buffer){
                        break;
                }else{
                        buf_itr += strlen(temp_buf);
                        strcat(buffer, temp_buf);
                        if(byte_itr+1 < packetsize){
                                strcat(buffer, ",");
                                buf_itr += 1;
                        }
                }
        }

        return buf_itr;
}

int main()
{
        uint8_t byte_array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
        char char_array[32]={0x00};
        int len = get_char(byte_array, 10, char_array, sizeof(char_array));
        printf("String  point %s : len %d\n", char_array, len);

}
```

NOTE:
when length return and size of output buffer same then buffer full condition happened.

Answer (score 2):

Two fixes:

- As you want to convert to char, then

`array_char[i]=my_byte[i]+0;` should be `array_char[i]=my_byte[i]+'0';` Note `'0'` is character (that will be converted to int) instead of numeric 0 (which doesn't do anything).

- Also you must free `temp` pointer in `main` as that memory is dynamically allocated in `get_char()` function.

---

Edit: just notice another issue in your `get_char()`

```
char *array_char=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```

should be

```
char *array_char= malloc(sizeof(char)*(packetsize+1));
```

After the `for` loop, ensure the buffer is NUL-terminated:

```
array_char[packetsize] = '\0';
```

Notice that your `packetsize` is never used - you should get some compiler warning about it. It's bad to hard code `10` in your `malloc` - it's actually the whole idea of parsing the `packetsize` as a parameter - so use it properly.

Comment: Also `printf("String  point %s ",data);` --> `printf("String  point %s ", temp);`

Comment: would suggest in your code that `array_char[packetsize] = '\0';` instead of just 0 (just to emphasize it's NUL character)

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch out for these things:

- You need to add a null-terminating character at the end of `*array_char`, otherwise using this pointer allocated from the heap will cause [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463241/not-null-terminating-a-c-style-string).
- You can simply allocate `*array_char` like this:

  ```
  char *array_char = malloc(packetsize+1);
  ```

  As `sizeof(char)` is `1`, and `+1` for trailing nullbyte.
- You also don't need to [cast return of malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).
- Instead of passing `10` as `packetsize` to `get_char()`, you should pass this size as `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]`, which is the calculated size of the array. This can be a `size_t` variable declared somewhere or even a macro.
- `malloc()` needs to be checked, as it can return `NULL` if unsuccessful.
- You need to [`free()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) `temp` at some point in the program.
- `array_char[i]=my_byte[i]+0;` needs to be `array_char[i]=my_byte[i]+'0';` instead, as `'0'` is the ascii code for a zero character.
- `char data` needs to be `char *data`, as `temp` is a pointer.

  If you compile with `-Wall -Wextra`, you will see that this line:

  ```
  data=*temp;
  ```

  Is dangerous, and will trigger warnings of making pointers from integers without a cast. It will most likely lead to a segmentation fault. If `temp` and `data` are both pointers, then you can simply use:

  ```
  data=temp;
  ```

  Which sets `data` to the address of `temp`. Sometimes this is written as   `data = &(*temp);`, but this is harder to read. Although their is no need for `data`, and using `temp` alone should be fine.

Your code can then look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]))

char *get_char(int my_byte[], size_t packetsize) {
    char *array_char = malloc(packetsize+1);
    const char ascii = '0';
    size_t i;  

    if (!array_char) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %zu bytes\n", packetsize+1);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < packetsize; i++) {
        array_char[i] = my_byte[i] + ascii;
    }
    array_char[i] = '\0'; /* or array_char[packetsize] = '\0' */           

    return array_char;
}

int main(void) {
    int byte_array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    char *temp, *data;

    temp = get_char(byte_array, ARRAYSIZE(byte_array));  
    data = temp;
    printf("String  point %s\n", data);

    printf("String converted into number = %d\n", atoi(data));

    free(temp);
    temp = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

You can also look into [`strtol`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html), which is better than using `atoi()` in terms of error checking.